# How to call scope in model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have the following method in model:

```
public function announcements()
    {
        return $this->categories()->with("announcements");
    }
```

And in the same model:

```
public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->where('votes', '>', 100);
    }
```

Hot to call this local scope in model for:

```
return $this->categories()->with("announcements")->active(); ?
```

Comment: What does the method `categories` look like? Is it returning a query builder instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the categories is an relation on this model and the announcements is a relation on the categories model.

Then you can try:

```
return $this->active()->categories->with("announcements")
```

`$this->active()` will return the active records of this model.

`->categories` will get the related categories

`->with("announcements")` will eager load the announcements of all the categories.

This will return an eloquent query builder instance.